# How to prevent clicking 2 times in a row on the InkWell button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the InkWell widget to add clickability, but I've run into the following problem: when I double-click on a button, I get 2 windows open at once. How to disable the ability to quickly press the button 2 times in a row?

**code**

```
Container(
            width: 72,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: onTap,
```

Comment: You can maintain a local state as well, on single click set var to false

Comment: Well, I need one window to open and after closing, I could open it again.
Now if I press 2 times in a row, 2 windows open.

Comment: You can create a guard clause with a counter variable. For instance when the user taps on the button increment the counter and execute the code only when the value is 1 otherwise do nothing. And when user closes the window decrement the counter. Not the best solution but it worked for me in other occasions.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll try it. Do you happen to have a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this trick?

`InkWell( onTap: onTap, onDoubleTap: (){}, )`